# Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Windows 8.0 and Android Studio 0.8.1 (also tried Android Studio 0.8).

When I click "New Project", nothing happens. If I try some of the other options such as open an existing project, the prompt appears, same with the settings option. I have tried installing JDK 8 as well, still seeing the same issue.

I am unable to locate any log files to give me more information. Does anyone know how I can fix this or where I can find log files to show me what the error is?

Comment: I bet you're saying 0.8.1, right? Otherwise, you're coming from the future which, at the same time, is awesome

Comment: :) yes I mean 0.8.1, unfortunately I am not coming from the future (this time).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had some errors on my disk which was causing this.

To fix this I did the following:

- Access my computer (Windows Key + E)
- Right click the C Drive
- Select properties
- Select the `Tools` tab
- Select `Check` under `Error checking`
- Ran the error check and rebooted to repair the drive
- I then deleted the following files under c:\Users[User name]\: `.android`, `.AndroidStudioBeta`, `.gradle`. (I was unable to delete these until I did the disk error checking).

After this, it was plain sailing.